# Redeclaration in function body with let and var

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function func(arg = 1) {
    var arg = 2; // success
    // let arg = 2; // SyntaxError: Identifier 'arg' has already been declared
}
```

I followed ECMA spec-7.0 [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) algorithm to see why exactly you can use `var` to redeclare a variable in the function body.

In step 21, all the parameters have been initialized. But the algorithm both use **CreateMutableBinding** to initialize variables declared in the body for `var`(27.f.i.2) and `let`(34.b.ii.1), so why does `var` succeed and `let` fail? What steps have I miss in the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is called an "Early Error", which is essentially an assertion that the spec declares should throw an error. In this case, [14.1.2 Static Semantics: Early Errors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors) states:

> It is a Syntax Error if any element of the `BoundNames` of `FormalParameters` also occurs in the `LexicallyDeclaredNames` of `FunctionBody`.

When you use `let` or `const` you are adding an item to the result of `LexicallyDeclaredNames`, which means they will conflict with the variables declared in the function params (`FormalParameters`).

Using `var` does not error because `LexicallyDeclaredNames` does not include `var` statements. Including `var`s in this error would be a backward-compatibility breaking change, so it does not error.